# iptables command to give internet to my guest OS via virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, iptables

Based on this [link](http://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/how-to-setup-a-virtual-lan-on-your-machine-using-oracle-virtualbox/) there is a difference between Host-only network and NAT. So I want to set the LAN connection between my host -14.04 ubuntu- and my guest XP by Host-only network.

How I can give internet connection to my XP?

Can any one give me iptables commands which I should write in order to give my XP machine access to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the host-only networking settings in VirtualBox is so that the guest OS *can only see the host*.  You could configure routing on your Ubuntu host so that the guest machine could use the internet after setting the host machine's IP address as the default gateway, but then you would be right back where you started (with your guest configured behind a NAT).

I would recommend that you set your networking settings on that guest back to NAT if you want to be able to access the internet from the guest.